# How to insert after the cursor in Vim visual block mode

Tags: vim

I want to insert text say `;` after the cursor in Vim visual mode.

```
Jan
Feb
Mar
```

`Ctrl + V` --> `jj` --> `Shift + i` results in

```
Ja;n
Fe;b
Ma;r
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like <kbd>i</kbd> inserts before the cursor and <kbd>a</kbd> inserts after the cursor in normal mode, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> inserts after the cursor in visual block mode.